# Is there a way to temporarily rebase a feature branch?

Tags: git

How can I take the set of commits in my branch, and rebase them to a temporary branch, and then rebase back to main?

More details-
My branch, `my-branch` depends on another code change `feature1` that a co-worker should push soon.
I don't want to wait for him, so I created `temp-feature1` that contains the desired change.
My plan was to rebase `my-branch` above `temp-feature1`, and rebase again to `main` once `main` contains the desired commit.

This is what I did:

**During develop**

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b temp-feature1
# commit temp changes that I want to depend on (feature1)
git checkout my-branch
```

And now I can develop without waiting for my college's commit.

Once `feature1` is merged to `main` I thought I can simply do -

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout my-branch
git rebase main
```

And remove my `temp-feature1` commit from the log, becuase it's already in `main`.

However, the rebase to main returned

```
Current branch my-branch is up to date.
```

And `temp-feature1` commit was still there.

Is there any way to get this workflow?

Comment: In practice, you might just be able to leave your fix commit in there and just merge the feature as you normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired workflow is totally normal and correct! The problem is merely that you gave the wrong `rebase` command. You should say

```
git rebase --onto main temp-feature1 my-branch
```

This will rip *just your `my-branch` branch* commits off of `temp-feature1` and shove them onto the end of `main`.

##### Before:

```
A -- B -- C (main) -- H -- I (temp-feature) -- X -- Y (my-branch)
```

##### After:

```
A -- B -- C (main) -- X -- Y (my-branch)
```

(PS You need to stop confusing `master` and `main`, I'm assuming that you mean `main` everywhere you say `master`. If you have both `main` and `master` you are probably in deep trouble.)

Comment: I'm using only `master` but I know it's not PC. Edited..

Comment: Well you said `master` in some places and `main` in others so it's just a matter of making up your mind. I don't care which it is but you can't have both.

Comment: You're still doing it.